# Difference between зарекомендовывать / рекомендовать?

Tags: выбор-слова

Would anybody be so kind and could explain me the difference between **зарекомендовывать** / **рекомендовать**?

I ask a couple of dictionaries but they stated always the same **to recommend**, this might be clear for the one without the prefix but not for one with the prefix right?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Зарекомендовывать* is just an imperfective form of *зарекомендовать*. But the verb *зарекомендовать* is in 99% cases used in expression *зарекомендовать себя* = *prove oneself*. So from this follows that imperfective *зарекомендовывать* is almost never used in speech.

That's a normal situation when using prefixes: almost any combination is legal, but only some are really useful. I have no idea where you've found "*зарекомендовывать*", but it's not of much use for your spoken practice. So just forget it.

Comment: Found it here, Task 1 at the third sentence. http://learnrussian.rt.com/lessons/short-form-of-adjectives/ And I'm not sure if I really should forget it. Mhh...

Comment: @SilvingsQuantu As I said, "зарекомендовать себя" is used often. And you definitely should remember this expression "as is". But "зарекомендовывать" is almost completely useless.

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендовать — to recommend.

Зарекомендовывать — imperfect form of Зарекомендовать:

Зарекомендовать себя с лучшей стороны — Proved itself with the best hand
Зарекомендовать себя с худшей стороны — To establish itself with the worst hand
Прослыть(зарекомендовать себя) азартным игроком — Pass gambler
Прослыть(зарекомендовать себя) обманщиком — Branded liar
Зарекомендовать себя ~ заслужить/заработать мнение о себе — Deserve opinion of himself; Make an opinion about himself.
Этот телефон зарекомендовал себя как очень надёжный — This phone has proved to be very reliable.